# Dystopian anime film where main (female) protagonist is saved from execution

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd like help to find a scene that I remember, but I totally forgot where I saw it. It's probably from an anime (and if it's that, it would be from an OVA), I don't think it's a film (though it still may). The set is quite futuristic, but guns still use bullets and the future doesn't seem very bright.

During the scene I'm talking about, the main character, female, is about to be shot by the villain, maybe some army guys? The main male character slowly falls upside down and shoots the bad guy before he could do anything. This is pretty much all I remember.

Comment: When you say "falls upside down" do you mean like a gravity effect?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [Patema Inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patema_Inverted)

A quasi-futuristic military hunts people who live under inverted gravity. Boy and girl from different gravitational pulls fall for each other. Boy saves girl. Sense of gravity is inverted part-way through.

Comment: Well... Since you've done a bit of a research, you can post a quote of a summary of the story and turn this into a real answer. Welcome to the site!